# How to know whether DHL Shipping is working

Tags: module, extensions, dhl

I recently added a `DHL` module on my site. I configured everything. from the admin. But I am not able to understand where should I see the module option on the frontend.

[image: admin]
This is my admin option for DHL.
[image: cart]
This is the image while checkout. No sign of DHL shipping. Is there any setting to enable on admin after enabling the DHL module? Please help me solving this.

Comment: Did you check the other informations below ? `Ship to Applicable Countries`, and `Ship to Specific Countries`. Also check if you are using the default config in the different scopes of the configuration

Comment: Yes. I added all the settings. The module allowed all country.

Comment: If you are working on a preprod server, try setting this two setting to _Yes_ : 
`Show Method if Not Applicable` and `Debug`. If the method doesn't display, the problem shouldn't be in the settings. And maybe the debug could help you out about where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Try this config:

[image]

this the config of the store that currently I am developing.